# How do I reinitialise $scope variables in a view's controller on reload in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, reload

I have a simple Angular webapp and I have problems when I re-visit a route. On first visit, the route's controller makes everything works as it should. On second visit, things break. The controller sets the dimension of a canvas element in the view. A stripped down example of the controller:

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module('noahdecocoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/particle-page', {
      templateUrl: 'views/particle.html',
      controller: 'ptclCtrl'
    })
});

// ptclCtrl.js
app.controller('ptclCtrl', function($scope){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("ptclCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width  = 500;
  ctx.canvas.height = 500;
});

//particle.html
<canvas id='ptclCanvas'></canvas
```

The first time around, this works fine. The second time around, the canvas resets to it's original default values. I'm not sure why this happens? Am I doing this wrong, is there an Angular way to do this? The second thing I'm trying to do is add and animate particles which I can't achieve because I suspect of the same problem, my Array variables only initialise on first load. Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to find the solution for weeks!

Comment: Can you post how you're doing routing, and how ptclCtrl is being used?

Comment: Sure! I just updated my post to include some of app.js and particle.html. This isn't the whole chunk, just the relative bits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not Angular at all. In angular you never ever ever (repeat that with me) do DOM manipulation in a controller. If you find doing that yourself, don't.

DOM manipulation is done in a directive, so you could do something like:

```
app.directive('resizeCanvas', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var ctx = element[0].getContext("2d");
      ctx.canvas.width  = 500;
      ctx.canvas.height = 500;
    } 
  };
});
```

and then:

```
<canvas resize-canvas></canvas>
```

That will resize it for you, no controller involved.

Comment: AHA! I knew it would be a question of 'thinking in Angular'. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. Wow, I'm going to have to relook all my other controllers now. But does this mean that I would add ALL my js code here? For example, I'll be adding and animating particles on the canvas, which would be interactive with the user's mouse. Would all that be placed here or is there another way in Angular. Any help pointing me in the right direction is very much appreciated!

Comment: By the way you explain it. Yeah, you could create a directive to do all those particles animation and stick it on the canvas like I did on my example.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help. It's the first time I'm trying anything with Angular and it really takes some rewiring the head to understand :D

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic that needs to be executed exactly once in the run block or the config. That way it gets initialized only once

Order of execution:

```
app.config()
app.run()
app.controller() 

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.run(function() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work. I need to call the script each time I'm on a particular view. I tried putting the script in a function in app.run and calling it from the ptclCtrl controller, but that gives me the same result I had when I started ie: works on first load, doesn't on second load.